# Position a div at bottom of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to set a div to the bottom of a page in a flex container.

Somehow, I am able to do it using:

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
```

But the div then wraps to the **whole viewport**.

I am trying to fix it in a single box.

Check the code. You will get the idea.

**https://jsfiddle.net/v3v1z7pv/**

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-flow: row;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box {
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
.whiteBox {
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="whiteBox">Whte box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add `position:relative` to `.box` . so the `whitebox` will stay inside it

> A page element with relative positioning gives you the control to absolutely position children elements inside of it.

see more here [relative absolute](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

```css
#container
{
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  flex-flow: row;
}
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.box
{
  min-width:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
}
.whiteBox
{
  bottom:10px;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="whiteBox">Whte box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `position:relative` to the `.box` element. Add that and you should get the result you want :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must use positioning, then add `position: relative` to the `box` class, so it becomes the bounding box (i.e., *nearest positioned ancestor*) for the absolutely-positioned `whiteBox` child.

Otherwise, you don't need absolute positioning for this task. It can be done purely with flex properties. With this method the `whiteBox` element is not removed from the [document flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow).

```
.box {
    min-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;             /* NEW */
}

.whiteBox {
    /* bottom: 10px; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    /* position: absolute; */
    align-self: flex-end;      /* NEW */
}
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-flow: row;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.box {
    min-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;             /* NEW */
}

.whiteBox {
    /* bottom: 10px; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    /* position: absolute; */
    align-self: flex-end;      /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="whiteBox">Whte box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3v1z7pv/2/)